# iOS UITableView how to disable scroll to bottom bouncing

Tags: ios, uitableview

I want to disable any scroll bouncing on my UITableView. For now I do it like that:

```
myTableView.bounces = NO;
```

But when I scroll to bottom of my list my content dont stop but back a little bit. How to disable this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just uncheck the Bounce Vertically property of UITableView

[image]

This can also be done programmatically by setting the alwaysBounceVertical property to NO

Answer (score 5):

```
-(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    if (scrollView.contentOffset.y<=0) {
        scrollView.contentOffset = CGPointZero;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

UITableview is inherited form UIScrollview.So simply use the scroll view delegates.We can do the same things which we are doing for a scrollview.Please correct me if am wrong.

Answer (score 2):

UITableView is a subclass of UIScrollView.
UIScrollView has a property you can set to stop the bouncing.

In fact there are two you could use:

set the `BOOL` value of `bounces` to `NO`.

set the `BOOL` value of `alwaysBounceVertical` to `NO`.

[Here's](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UIScrollView) the link to the docs.